# "sh: wine: command not found" on Mac, despite wine installed?

Tags: terminal, command-line, homebrew, path, wine

Hello, all. I have been using [*Wineskin Winery*](http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-index.php) to run Windows programs for almost a decade at this point, and though I have already gone through my fair share of issues (using winetricks, checking engine versions, etc), a Wine app has mysteriously stopped working because seemingly wine is not detected.

For years, an old Wineskin app had been working faithfully for me, until I decided to go and install [*Porting Kit*](https://portingkit.com/) (which is the semi-successor to Wineskin Winery, and is suppose to be able to run the former's apps). Now, my app does not open, and the Test log reports this:

```
sh: wine: command not found
```

Homebrew installed wine, and if `which wine` is ran in Terminal, I get `/usr/local/bin/wine`, so why would Porting Kit report not finding it? This does not look like a simple `PATH` issue, and I have tried uninstalling and installing wine already.

It would be appreciated it if the community could share any suggestions on what I could do to fix this.

Comment: Have you tried running wine from the terminal?

Comment: It runs, but I need the Wineskin wrapper to work, and it runs wine on its own.

Comment: is Wireskin an app like Wine?  Have you done 'which wineskin'?

Comment: Wineskin (http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-index.php), is probably the main and easiest way to use Wine.

`which wineskin` does not reveal anything because it is a `.app`, not something installed with terminal.

Comment: Wineskin Wrappers (which are the kind of app that both Porting Kit and Wineskin Winery create) have their own Wine binaries inside. If you updated to macOS Catalina or Big Sur before the problem started, that may be the source of your issue, considering you mentioned that you used this wrapper for almost a decade, and that only recently there were Wine binaries that are capable of running in macOS Big Sur at all, or in Catalina without tweaking the system settings. Summarising: you should properly try to recreate that wrapper with modern Wineskin Winery or Porting Kit

Comment: This is where you can find the most recent Wineskin Winery version: https://github.com/Gcenx/WineskinServer/